# Marshal and unmarshal protocol buffers in python

Tags: python-3.x, go, protocol-buffers, marshalling, unmarshalling

In Go there is a [proto package](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto) which provides marshal and unmarshal function/methods which encodes and decodes in wire format.

This link https://gist.github.com/miguelmota/25568433ad8cfddb5ea556a5644c9fde provides an example of marshal and unmarshal in Go.

Can I do marshal and unmarshal in python? If yes, which package should I use to achieve this functionality?

Comment: @Flimzy no that doesn't answer my question. I want to know how to marshal and unmarshal in python. And if data is marshalled in one language (Golang) can I unmarshal in other languages(python)

Comment: Protocol buffers are language-agnostic. You just need to use the Python support for protobuf, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: I used this link (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial) to encode(Marshal) and decode(Unmarshal) the data in python.

Comment: Hey @YaseenHussain how did you do? There’s no encoding in that link you shared.

Comment: I couldn't do it. I did it in go only.